# Temp table intermittent issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, temp-tables

We used to have a really badly performing CTE that used to take 3-5 mins to execute. I have modified the CTE and used a function with temp tables to accomplish the same task. Now the new function runs in less than 5 secs.

This is what I did:

From

```
    WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    ),
    CTE2 AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    ),
    CTEn AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    )
    SELECT A,B,C,D
    FROM CTE1
    JOIN CTE2 ON ...
    JOIN CTEn ON ...;
```

TO

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_ABC(a integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(A integer, B integer, C integer, D integer)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
    DECLARE
    x ALIAS for $1;
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CTE1;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CTE2;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CTEn;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE CTE1 AS
    ( SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    );
    CREATE TEMP TABLE CTE2 AS
    ( SELECT ...
    FROM ...);
    CREATE TEMP TABLE CTEn AS
    ( SELECT ...
    FROM ...);
    CREATE INDEX ix_cte1 ON CTE1(A);
    CREATE INDEX ix_cte2 ON CTE2(B);
    CREATE INDEX ix_cten ON CTEn(C);
    CREATE INDEX ix_cten ON CTEn(D);
    RETURNS QUERY SELECT A,B,C,D
    FROM CTE1
    JOIN CTE2 ON ...
    JOIN CTEn ON ...
    END;
    $function$
;
```

As I stated above, the function pretty fast. The reason behind adding "DROP TABLE" is that, within a transaction, this function can be executed any number of times. But, intermittently, we see an error like:

`ERROR:  must be owner of relation CTE1`

I am not able to reproduce this error. And there is only one user that runs this function. No other user has permissions to execute this function.

I couldn't think of a scenario when this would fail. Any thoughts of insights will be appreciated.

Comment: This is in postgresql 9.3 btw.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.